# Load Latest Posts First From Bottom To Top

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, rows

As the title says I am trying to get a facebook like functionality but for some reasons when I apply it to a left join query I get duplicate 'post_id' column whys that? :/

I assume I explained it enough that I want the latest post to display down the bottom first (bottom to top and looking at the query should explain you more what I want)

Here's the working query (no left join but I need left join to load all comments on each post)

```
  Working: (need the left join functions though)

$select_post_comments = $db->query("SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."groups_comments
        WHERE post_id='$escape_post_id_row'
        ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 7
) a ORDER BY comment_id");
```

Getting the Duplicate post_id error :/

```
    $select_post_comments = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ( 
                SELECT * FROM spud_groups_posts 
                LEFT JOIN spud_groups_comments ON spud_groups_posts.post_id = spud_groups_comments.post_id 
                WHERE spud_groups_posts.post_id='$post_id_feed'     ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 7
) a ORDER BY comment_id");
```

What is causing me to get this error I have tried everything to my knowledge

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post_id` is a column in both the tables `spud_groups_posts` and `spud_groups_comments` and you are doing a JOIN and selecting all columns causing the duplicate column error

select column name with table name prefix and also select only required columns

```
 SELECT spud_groups_posts.post_id as sgpostid, spud_groups_comments.comment_id 
 FROM spud_groups_posts
 LEFT JOIN spud_groups_comments 
 ON spud_groups_posts.post_id = spud_groups_comments.post_id
```

Comment: @Jan Dooly, you can accept the answer if it is helpful